# Build in type() function behaviour differs when run in method

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm fairly new to Python and I don't understand this behavior:

```
In [62]: a = "string"

In [63]: type(a)                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[63]: str

In [64]: def some_method(what):                                                                                                                                                                             
             var = type(what)
             if var == "str":
                 print("it is str")
             else:
                 print("it's NOT str")
             print("Val of passed arg is - ", what, "And 'var' is - ", var)

In [65]: some_method(a)                                                                                                                                                                                     
it's NOT str
Val of passed arg is -  string And 'var' is -  <class 'str'>
```

Could anyone explain as to why variable "var" has a value "class 'str'",

instead of how it's displayed in ipython3 RAPL - "str"?

Thanks.

Comment: Big thanks to all of you, guys, for a clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing the type of a variable to a string rather than to a type. Just drop the quotes in your if-clause:

```
>>> a = "string"
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(a) == str
True
>>> type(a) == "str"
False
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that.

Answer (score 4):

No it doesn't. In neither of those cases is the type equal to the string `"str"`. It's equal to the *type* `str`.

In any case, to check if something is a string, you should use `isinstance`, again with the actual type object.

```
if isinstance(var, str):
    print("it is str")
```

Comment: I knew about `isinstance` just decided to make similar method myself, which now I'm one more time acknowledging is not a good thing to do ) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is just IPython's way of displaying things. `str` isn't equal to `'str'`:

```
In [14]: type(a) == "str"
Out[14]: False
```

IPython defines its own `displayhook` which displays results to you, the original `displayhook` (found in `sys.__displayhook__`) makes this clear:

```
In [15]: sys.__displayhook__(type(''))
<class 'str'>
```